# Редирект не возвращает значение

Tags: php

Почему не выводит значение переменной $category?
index.php

```
   <form method="POST"  action="category.php" >
    <div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="id_category" value="1">
    </div>
    </form>
```

category.php

```
 <?php
    $category=$_POST['id_category']; 
    header('location:goods.php');
    ?>
```

goods.php

```
 <? 
    error_reporting('E_ALL');
    include 'category.php';
    echo "$category"; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Потому что в category.php вы её никак не используете и она просто уничтожается после работы скрипта, а в goods.php вы её ниоткуда не берёте и поэтому её не существует. Это два разных скрипта, они запускаются в разное время, и нет ни одной причины, по которой у них бы откуда-то взялись общие переменные

Comment: Хотя ваш `include 'category.php'` по идее вообще должен создать бесконечный редирект...

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы не можете отправить редирект пользователю, сохранив при этом POST-данные. Используйте сессии для этого
2. А почему бы в форме сразу не указать `action="goods.php"`? Вам будет проще сделать так, чем, во-первых, делать редирект на другой скрипт, во-вторых, думать, куда запихнуть данные, чтобы второй скрипт смог до них добраться.
3. В `category.php` происходит редирект на `goods.php`, но в `goods.php` происходит инклуд `category.php`. По сути у Вас должно произойти зацикливание, поскольку первый перенаправляет на второй, а второй инклудит первый.
4. Маленькое замечание. В `goods.php` в строке `echo "$category";` кавычки использовать необязательно. Можно написать и так: `echo $category;`

Comment: пытаюсь обойти повторную отправку формы поэтому использую редирект как это правильно делается?

Comment: В таком случае делайте это через сессии: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php